# Use flutter to create a platform neutral SDK

Tags: flutter

Flutter makes it pretty simple to use platform features/native SDKs within a flutter application. However, does anyone know if the opposite is possible?

What I'd love to do is create an SDK in dart/flutter that can be used by mobile developers on their preferred platform.

Comment: Can you describe what your SDK does? Are you drawing UI on the screen or doing something else in Dart?

Comment: The SDK would encapsulate a server API

Comment: I don't think Flutter is adding much value in this case